# MYSQL - Get Next and Previous Record by ID - HTML for hyperlinks

Tags: php, mysql, html, variables, hyperlink

So I'm trying to add a little bit of convenience to a CRUD by adding next and previous links to navigate between records in my database.

**Here are my queries:**

```
$id=$_GET['id'];
$id = $currentid;
$prevquery= "SELECT * FROM inventory WHERE id < $currentid ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1"; 
$prevresult = mysql_query($prevquery);

$nextquery= "SELECT * FROM inventory WHERE id > $currentid ORDER BY id ASC LIMIT 1"; 
$nextresult = mysql_query($nextquery);
?>
```

**Here is my HTML:**

```
<a href="http://www.url.com/crud/edit.php?id=<?php echo $prevresult; ?> ">Previous</a>

<a href="http://www.url.com/crud/edit.php?id=<?php echo $nextresult; ?> ">Next</a>
```

Now I tested these queries in PHPMyAdmin and they produced the result I wanted, but I can't get my hyperlinks to actually be supplied with the correct IDs... they're just blank after the =. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions for new code. They are no longer maintained and the community has begun the [deprecation process](http://goo.gl/KJveJ). See the [**red box**](http://goo.gl/GPmFd)? Instead you should learn about [prepared statements](http://goo.gl/vn8zQ) and use either [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli). If you can't decide, [this article](http://goo.gl/3gqF9) will help to choose. If you care to learn, [here is good PDO tutorial](http://goo.gl/vFWnC).

Comment: shouldn't it be $currentid = $id;?

Answer (score 10):

`mysql_query`() returns a result set (resource).  To get the actual rows from the result set, you need to use a function like [`mysql_fetch_row()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-fetch-row.php).

Your code for the "next" link would look *something like*:

**PHP**

```
$nextquery= "SELECT * FROM inventory WHERE id > $currentid ORDER BY id ASC LIMIT 1"; 
$nextresult = mysql_query($nextquery);
if(mysql_num_rows($nextresult) > 0)
{
    $nextrow = mysql_fetch_row($nextresult);
    $nextid  = $nextrow['id'];
}
```

**HTML**

```
<a href="http://www.url.com/crud/edit.php?id=<?php echo $nextid; ?> ">Next</a>
```

and the previous link would be done similarly.

***Obligatory note:*** For new code, you should seriously consider using [PDO](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.pdo-mysql.php).

**Advanced note**:
You could combine your queries into a single query like:

```
SELECT
  (
    SELECT id
    FROM inventory WHERE id < $currentid ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1
  ) AS previd,
  (
    SELECT id
    FROM inventory WHERE id > $currentid ORDER BY id ASC LIMIT 1
  ) AS nextid
```

And then adjust the logic accordingly.

Comment: That's probably a step in the right direction, but my error log is saying:

[25-Jun-2012 12:22:47] PHP Warning:  Wrong parameter count for mysql_num_rows() in /url/usr/public_html/crud/edit.php on line 144

[25-Jun-2012 12:22:47] PHP Warning:  Wrong parameter count for mysql_num_rows() in /url/usr/public_html/crud/edit.php on line 152

Comment: Ya, you have to pass it the result resource, try the updated code.

Comment: Now getting: PHP Warning:  mysql_num_rows(): supplied argument is not a valid MySQL result resource in....

Comment: That means there is an error -- add `print_r(mysql_error());` after the `mysql_query()` line and see what it says.

Comment: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'ORDER BY id ASC LIMIT 1' at line 1

Comment: Print your query too, to make sure it is formatted correctly: `print_r($nextquery)`.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, It took a little bit but I figured it out...

**PHP**

```
$prevquery= "SELECT * FROM inventory WHERE id < $currentid ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1"; 
$prevresult = mysql_query($prevquery) or die(mysql_error());
while($prevrow = mysql_fetch_array($prevresult))
{
$previd  = $prevrow['id'];
}

$nextquery= "SELECT * FROM inventory WHERE id > $currentid ORDER BY id ASC LIMIT 1"; 
$nextresult = mysql_query($nextquery) or die(mysql_error());
while($nextrow = mysql_fetch_array($nextresult))
{
$nextid  = $nextrow['id'];
}
```

**HTML**

```
<a href="http://www.theantiquarium.com/crud/edit.php?id=<?php echo $previd; ?>">Previous</a>

<a href="http://www.theantiquarium.com/crud/edit.php?id=<?php echo $nextid; ?>">Next</a>
```

Thanks for the help, I think it put me on the right course. I'll look into that PDO stuff for the future. I'm just now starting to get a hang of the old MYSQL/PHP syntax and now all the sudden there's a new format... tough to keep up with it all!

Comment: Since you're limiting your result set to a size of 1, you don't need the while loop, it would, however, hide the error that would occur when the query returned a result set of size 0.  It may not matter to you since you're still learning, but you should at least understand why the while loop is unnecessary (and possibly bug-introducing).  Anyway, congrats on getting it to work!

Answer (score 0):

The resultant code has a culprit at the very beginning and end of the table. Your code will "die" as you ordered. Instead you might check the query results ($prevresult, $nextresult) and decide NOT to show a link for previous or next item.

Answer (score -2):

SELECT 
IFNULL(
(SELECT id FROM inventory WHERE id < $currentid ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1 ) , (SELECT id FROM inventory ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1 )
) AS previd , 
IFNULL(
(SELECT id FROM inventory WHERE id > $currentid ORDER BY id ASC LIMIT 1 ), 
(SELECT id FROM inventory ORDER BY id ASC LIMIT 1 )
) AS nextid